# Count Unique Combinations Meeting Specific Criteria

Tags: r, group-by, count, unique, combinations

**The Problem:**

I would like to count the number of unique 5-player combinations `n`, which meet the criteria described below, for each team using the following data.

**The Data:**

```
TEAM <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
PLAYER <- c("Will","Will","Roy","Roy","Jaylon","Dean","Yosef","Devan","Quincy","Quincy","Luis","Xzavier","Seth","Layne","Layne","Antwan")
LP <- c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,6)
POS <- c("3B","OF","1B","OF","SS","OF","C","OF","2B","OF","OF","C","3B","1B","OF","SS")
df <- data.frame(TEAM,PLAYER,LP,POS)
```

df:

```
    TEAM  PLAYER   LP  POS
 1  A     Will     1   3B
 2  A     Will     1   OF
 3  A     Roy      2   1B
 4  A     Roy      3   OF
 5  A     Jaylon   3   SS
 6  A     Dean     4   OF
 7  A     Yosef    5   C
 8  A     Devan    6   OF
 9  B     Quincy   1   2B
10  B     Quincy   1   OF
11  B     Luis     2   OF
12  B     Xzavier  3   C
13  B     Seth     4   3B
14  B     Layne    5   1B
15  B     Layne    5   OF
16  B     Antwan   6   SS
```

Edit: The `LP` column is irrelevant to the output. That wasn't as clear as I would have liked it to be in the original post.

**The Criteria:**

1. Five unique players `PLAYER` must be used (one will always be left out, as there are six players in the pool available for each team).
2. Each position `POS` may only be used once with the exception of `OF`, which may be used up to three times `OF <= 3`.
3. Combinations may not use players `PLAYER` from multiple teams `TEAM`.

**For Example:**

These are just a few of the many possible combinations I am looking to create/count:

```
   TEAM  1          2          3          4         5
1  A     Will-OF    Roy-1B     Jaylon-SS  Dean-OF   Devan-OF
2  A     Roy-OF     Jaylon-SS  Dean-OF    Yosef-C   Devan-OF
3  A     Will-3B    Roy-OF     Jaylon-SS  Dean-OF   Yosef-C
...
n  A     Will-3B    Roy-1B     Jaylon-SS  Dean-OF   Yosef-C       

   TEAM  1          2          3          4         5
1  B     Quincy-2B  Luis-OF    Xzavier-C  Seth-3B   Layne-1B
2  B     Quincy-2B  Luis-OF    Seth-3B    Layne-1B  Antwan-SS
3  B     Quincy-OF  Luis-OF    Xzavier-C  Seth-3B   Layne-OF
...
n  B     Quincy-2B  Luis-OF    Xzavier-C  Seth-3B   Layne-OF
```

**Desired Result:**

```
TEAM  UNIQUE
A     n
B     n
```

**What I've Tried:**

I know how to get all possible 5-player combinations for each team and summarise that. I'm just not sure how to get the combinations I'm looking for using the specific criteria as defined for their positions.

I wish I knew where to begin with this one. I could really use your help. Thank you!

Comment: What is `n` in the dessired result

Comment: Do you need `df %>% unite(LPPOS, LP, POS) %>% group_by(TEAM) %>% summarise(UNIQUE = nrow(RcppAlgos::comboGeneral(LPPOS, n()-1)))`

Comment: `n` is the number of total possible unique 5-player/position combinations that can be created using the criteria described (in the format of the example).

Comment: can other POS beside OF be duplicated within a team?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider several wrangling steps:

1. Assign new column as concatenation of `PLAYER` and `POS`.
2. Run `by` to split data frame by teams and run operations on splits (Rule #3).
3. Run `combn` on `PLAYER_POS` to choose 5 listings.
4. Run `ave` for running count of similar `PLAYER`.
5. Run `Filter` to keep data frames of 5 rows, 5 unique players, and adheres to positions criteria (Rule #1 and #2).

Base R code

```
# HELPER COLUMN
df$PLAYER_POS <- with(df, paste(PLAYER, POS, sep="_"))

# BUILD LIST OF DFs BY TEAM
df_list <- by(df, df$TEAM, function(sub){
  combn(sub$PLAYER_POS, 5, FUN = function(p) 
    transform(subset(sub, PLAYER_POS %in% p),
              PLAYER_NUM = ave(LP, PLAYER, FUN=seq_along)), 
    simplify = FALSE)
})
  
# FILTER LIST OF DFs BY TEAM
df_list <- lapply(df_list, function(dfs) 
  Filter(function(df) 
           nrow(df) == 5 & 
           max(df$PLAYER_NUM)==1 &
           length(df$POS[df$POS == "OF"]) <= 3 &
           length(df$POS[df$POS != "OF"]) == length(unique(df$POS[df$POS != "OF"])), 
         dfs)
)

# COUNT REMAINING DFs BY TEAM FOR UNIQUE n
lengths(df_list)
#  A  B 
# 18 20 

data.frame(TEAMS=names(df_list), UNIQUE=lengths(df_list), row.names=NULL)
#   TEAMS UNIQUE
# 1     A     18
# 2     B     20
```

**Output** *(list of subsetted data frames)*

```
df_list$A[[1]]
#   TEAM PLAYER LP POS PLAYER_POS PLAYER_NUM
# 1    A   Will  1  3B    Will_3B          1
# 3    A    Roy  2  1B     Roy_1B          1
# 5    A Jaylon  3  SS  Jaylon_SS          1
# 6    A   Dean  4  OF    Dean_OF          1
# 7    A  Yosef  5   C    Yosef_C          1
df_list$A[[2]]
df_list$A[[3]]
...
df_list$A[[18]]


df_list$B[[1]]
#    TEAM  PLAYER LP POS PLAYER_POS PLAYER_NUM
# 9     B  Quincy  1  2B  Quincy_2B          1
# 11    B    Luis  2  OF    Luis_OF          1
# 12    B Xzavier  3   C  Xzavier_C          1
# 13    B    Seth  4  3B    Seth_3B          1
# 14    B   Layne  5  1B   Layne_1B          1
df_list$B[[2]]
df_list$B[[3]]
...
df_list$B[[20]]
```

Comment: @CPak, I do not understand your question. What do you mean by *valid* and what do you mean by *group*?

Comment: Nevermind, I see you you have shown the `n` per `TEAM` already in your answer

Answer (score 0):

## A messier solution,

I worked on this through the morning and just got to my solution (only to see there is a more elegant one posted.  But I offer this up to you anyways to share my thought process on how I arrived at the solution.

```
        library(tidyverse)
    
    TEAM <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
    PLAYER <- c("Will","Will","Roy","Roy","Jaylon","Dean","Yosef","Devan","Quincy","Quincy","Luis","Xzavier","Seth","Layne","Layne","Antwan")
    LP <- c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,6)
    POS <- c("3B","OF","1B","OF","SS","OF","C","OF","2B","OF","OF","C","3B","1B","OF","SS")
    df <- data.frame(TEAM,PLAYER,LP,POS)
    rm(TEAM, PLAYER, LP, POS)
    
    # Each team has 6 players and I want to find the groups of 5 that are possible.
    posible_player_combinations <- combn(1:6, 5) %>% as_tibble() 
    team = "A"
    
    make_2nd_column <- function(first_stage, mydata_byteam, pcomp){
      mydf <- mydata_byteam %>% filter(LP == pcomp[2])
      col2_filter <- tibble(
        col1LP =  rep(first_stage$LP, each = nrow(mydf)),
        col1POS = rep(first_stage$POS, each = nrow(mydf)))
      helper <- tibble(
        col2LP = rep(mydf$LP, nrow(first_stage)),
        col2POS = rep(mydf$POS, nrow(first_stage))
      )
      col2_filter <- cbind(col2_filter, helper)
      second_stage <- col2_filter %>% filter(col1POS != col2POS)
      return(second_stage)
    }
    make_3rd_column <- function(second_stage, mydata_byteam, pcomp){
      mydf <- mydata_byteam %>% filter(LP == pcomp[3])
      col3_filter <- tibble(
        col1LP =  rep(second_stage$col1LP, each = nrow(mydf)),
        col1POS = rep(second_stage$col1POS, each = nrow(mydf)),
        col2LP =  rep(second_stage$col2LP, each = nrow(mydf)),
        col2POS = rep(second_stage$col2POS, each = nrow(mydf)))
      helper <- tibble(
        col3LP = rep(mydf$LP, nrow(second_stage)),
        col3POS = rep(mydf$POS, nrow(second_stage))
      )
      col3_filter <- cbind(col3_filter, helper)
      third_stage <- col3_filter %>% filter(col1POS != col2POS,
                                            col2POS != col3POS,
                                            col3POS != col1POS)
      return(third_stage)
    }
    make_4th_column <- function(third_stage, mydata_byteam, pcomp){
      mydf <- mydata_byteam %>% filter(LP == pcomp[4])
      col4_filter <- tibble(
        col1LP =  rep(third_stage$col1LP, each = nrow(mydf)),
        col1POS = rep(third_stage$col1POS, each = nrow(mydf)),
        col2LP =  rep(third_stage$col2LP, each = nrow(mydf)),
        col2POS = rep(third_stage$col2POS, each = nrow(mydf)),
        col3LP =  rep(third_stage$col3LP, each = nrow(mydf)),
        col3POS = rep(third_stage$col3POS, each = nrow(mydf)))
      helper <- tibble(
        col4LP = rep(mydf$LP, nrow(third_stage)),
        col4POS = rep(mydf$POS, nrow(third_stage))
      )
      col4_filter <- cbind(col4_filter, helper)
      fourth_stage <- col4_filter %>% filter(col1POS != col2POS,
                                             col1POS != col3POS,
                                             col1POS != col4POS,
                                             col2POS != col3POS,
                                             col2POS != col4POS,
                                             col3POS != col4POS)
      return(fourth_stage)
    }
    make_5th_column <- function(fourth_stage, mydata_byteam, pcomp){
      mydf <- mydata_byteam %>% filter(LP == pcomp[5])
      col5_filter <- tibble(
        col1LP =  rep(fourth_stage$col1LP, each = nrow(mydf)),
        col1POS = rep(fourth_stage$col1POS, each = nrow(mydf)),
        col2LP =  rep(fourth_stage$col2LP, each = nrow(mydf)),
        col2POS = rep(fourth_stage$col2POS, each = nrow(mydf)),
        col3LP =  rep(fourth_stage$col3LP, each = nrow(mydf)),
        col3POS = rep(fourth_stage$col3POS, each = nrow(mydf)),
        col4LP =  rep(fourth_stage$col4LP, each = nrow(mydf)),
        col4POS = rep(fourth_stage$col4POS, each = nrow(mydf)))
      helper <- tibble(
        col5LP = rep(mydf$LP, nrow(fourth_stage)),
        col5POS = rep(mydf$POS, nrow(fourth_stage))
      )
      col5_filter <- cbind(col5_filter, helper)
      final_stage_prefilter <- col5_filter %>% filter(
        col1POS != col2POS,
        col1POS != col3POS,
        col1POS != col4POS,
        col1POS != col5POS,
        col2POS != col3POS,
        col2POS != col4POS,
        col2POS != col5POS,
        col3POS != col4POS,
        col3POS != col5POS,
        col4POS != col5POS)
      return(final_stage_prefilter)
    }
    make_final <- function(final_stage_prefilter){
      final_stage_prefilter %>% mutate(
        Player1 = paste(col1LP, str_remove_all(col1POS, "-.*")),
        Player2 = paste(col2LP, str_remove_all(col2POS, "-.*")),
        Player3 = paste(col3LP, str_remove_all(col3POS, "-.*")),
        Player4 = paste(col4LP, str_remove_all(col4POS, "-.*")),
        Player5 = paste(col5LP, str_remove_all(col5POS, "-.*"))
      ) %>% select(
        11:15
      ) %>% distinct()
    }
    
    make_teams <- function(posible_player_combinations, mydata, k){
      pcomp  <- posible_player_combinations[k] %>% as_vector() %>% unname()
      mydata_byteam <- mydata %>% filter(LP %in% pcomp)
      first_stage            <- mydata_byteam %>% filter(LP == pcomp[1])
      second_stage           <- make_2nd_column(first_stage, mydata_byteam, pcomp)
      third_stage            <- make_3rd_column(second_stage, mydata_byteam, pcomp)
      fourth_stage           <- make_4th_column(third_stage, mydata_byteam, pcomp)
      final_stage_prefilter  <- make_5th_column(fourth_stage, mydata_byteam, pcomp)
      final_stage            <- make_final(final_stage_prefilter)
      return(final_stage)
    }
    
    
    make_all_combinations <- function(df, team, posible_player_combinations) {
      mydata <- df %>% filter(TEAM == team) %>% select(LP, POS)
      of_p <- mydata %>% filter(POS == "OF") %>% select(LP) %>% as_vector()
      # I want to treat 3 possible "OF"s as separate positions
      # so that that a later restirction on POS can occur.
      # Later I will need to filter out non-unique results
      # by separating the strings with "-" and dropping the letter.
      of_df <- bind_rows(lapply(
        seq_along(of_p),
        function(x, k){
          of_df <- tibble(
            LP = rep(of_p[k], 3),
            POS = c("OF-a", "OF-b", "OF-c")
          )
        },
        x = of_p
      ))
      mydata <- rbind(mydata %>% filter(POS != "OF"), of_df)
      all_combinations <- bind_rows(lapply(
        X = seq_along(posible_player_combinations),
        FUN = make_teams,
        posible_player_combinations = posible_player_combinations,
        mydata = mydata
      ))
    }
mydata_a <- make_all_combinations(df, "A", posible_player_combinations)
mydata_b <- make_all_combinations(df, "B", posible_player_combinations)

tail(mydata_a)
tail(mydata_b)

# > tail(mydata_a)
#      Player1 Player2 Player3 Player4 Player5
# 13    1 3B    2 OF    4 OF     5 C    6 OF
# 14    1 OF    2 1B    4 OF     5 C    6 OF
# 15    1 3B    3 SS    4 OF     5 C    6 OF
# 16    1 OF    3 SS    4 OF     5 C    6 OF
# 17    2 1B    3 SS    4 OF     5 C    6 OF
# 18    2 OF    3 SS    4 OF     5 C    6 OF
# > tail(mydata_b)
#      Player1 Player2 Player3 Player4 Player5
# 15    1 2B     3 C    4 3B    5 1B    6 SS
# 16    1 2B     3 C    4 3B    5 OF    6 SS
# 17    1 OF     3 C    4 3B    5 1B    6 SS
# 18    1 OF     3 C    4 3B    5 OF    6 SS
# 19    2 OF     3 C    4 3B    5 1B    6 SS
# 20    2 OF     3 C    4 3B    5 OF    6 SS
```